# RegEx to exclude word starts with symbol "]"

Tags: php, regex

now i have regex that just capture words from content

```
/\b(word1|word2|word3)\b/i
```

its quite simple and it works, but i have a case when it shouldn't fire. When word is in wordpress shortcode

[voice]word1[/voice]

In this case regex doesn't need to be fired.
I've tried `[^\]]\b(word1|word2|word3)\b` but it captures extra space. Check https://regex101.com/r/KdEvbN/1

I spent about 2 hours and now i hate regex. Help me get out. Thanks

Comment: Maybe `'~\[(\w+)\b[^][]*].*?\[\/\1](*SKIP)(*F)|\b(word1|word2|word3)\b~'` will do better ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/825CVb/1)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow, thanks for the answer. This is looks scary, but it seems to work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try a negative look behind like this:

```
(?<!])\b(word1|word2|word3)\b
```

Comment: That's what i need! Thank you so much!

Comment: An issue is that when you have space(s) like this it will still match: [voice] word1[/voice]

Comment: this case with space(s) is not possible in my project. Your answer already works, thanks again amalgamate